# How to show and hide a long list of divs using jquery in short form

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have, and it works. I was wondering if anybody with more experience could shed some light on how to do this in less lines of code.

```
    $(function(){
    $("#div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6, #back").hide();
    $("#next").on("click", function(){
    if($("#div1").is(":visible")){
        $("#back").show();
        $("#div2").show();
        $("#div1").hide();
    }
    else if($("#div2").is(":visible")){
        $("#div3").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
    }
    else if($("#div3").is(":visible")){
        $("#div4").show();
        $("#div3").hide();
    }
    else if($("#div4").is(":visible")){
        $("#div5").show();
        $("#div4").hide();
    }
    else if($("#div5").is(":visible")){
        $("#div6").show();
        $("#div5").hide();
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: please also show the html, may create a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea:

```
$(function(){
    $("#div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6, #back").hide();

    $("#btnNext").on("click", function(){
       var checked = false;
        $("div").each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":visible"))
            {
                if (!checked)
                {
                    $(this).next().show();
                    $(this).hide();
                    checked = true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QYMEb/

Comment: I'd also say that saying `$("#div1").show()` would be better than hiding the rest. just hide them using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/DomDay/vy5U4/6

```
<div class="div-stepper">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>

    ... arbitrary number of divs ...

    <div>div n-1</div>
    <div>div n</div>
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <div id="back">back</div>
    <div id="next">next</div>
</div>
```

js

```
resetStepper()

$('#next').on( 'click', function() {
    $active = $('.div-stepper .active:not(:last-child)');
    $active.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    $('#back').show();    
});

$('#back').on( 'click', resetStepper );

function resetStepper() {
    $('.div-stepper div').removeClass('active');
    $('.div-stepper div:first-child').addClass('active');
    $('#back').hide();    
}
```

this doesn't rely on the div id, but for convenience, uses a wrapper div with a class.

( edit. forgot the "back" button )

( edit. to include "back"/"next" button click functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/DomDay/vy5U4/6/ )

Comment: :last-child isn't my favorite

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div id="back">back</div>
<div>
<div id="div1">div 1</div>
<div id="div2">div 2</div>
<div id="div3">div 3</div>
<div id="div4">div 4</div>
<div id="div5">div 5</div>
<div id="div6">div 6</div>
</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("#div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6, #back").hide();
    $("#next").on("click", function(){
        $("[id^=div]:visible").hide().next().show();
        $("#back").show();
        if($("[id^=div]:visible").index() === $("[id^=div]").length-1) { $("#next").hide(); }
    });
    $("#back").on("click", function(){
        $("[id^=div]:visible").hide().prev().show();
        $("#next").show();
        if($("[id^=div]:visible").index() === 0) { $("#back").hide(); }
    });    
 });
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/E5h8C/)

Comment: I too would set the initial state using CSS rather than a hide();